# No position entries for this simple turtle strategy

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to back test a strategy called the Turtle Trading System with a few tweaks, but no entries are submitted.There are basically two systems in this strategy(short-term breakout and long-term breakout),and there are three conditions for each.

I tried if statements and even applied conditions separately,but nothing works.Is there anything wrong with the logic of my code?

```
//@version=4

strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=2)

//Calculate EMAs
emaFast = ema(close, 30)
emaSlow = ema(close, 60)
emaLong = ema(close, 100)

// Determine entry conditions
breakoutST = (emaFast > emaSlow) and (close > emaLong) and (close > high[24])
breakoutLT = (emaFast > emaSlow) and (close > emaLong) and (close > high[48])

// Submit entry orders
if (breakoutST)
    strategy.entry(id="Buy", long=true)

if (breakoutLT)
    strategy.entry(id="Buy", long=true)

// Exit conditions
exitLong1 = close < low[24]
exitLong2 = close < low[48]


// Exit trades
if (exitLong1)
    strategy.close(id="Sell")

if (exitLong2)
    strategy.close(id="Sell")
```

Trades should occur in both systems,and I see no trades.Could you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the **same** order id that you want to close in your `strategy.close()`.

```
// Exit trades
if (exitLong1)
    strategy.close(id="Buy")

if (exitLong2)
    strategy.close(id="Buy")
```